# Is it possible to have a different Application.RTD.ThrottleInterval for different Workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba, real-time-data, rtd

I have two workbooks that have RTD links (Real Time Data). On most of my workbooks, i dont need the data to update faster than once every 4-5 seconds, however - I would need only 1 of my workbooks to update as fast as possible (Application.RTD.ThrottleInterval=0).

Is it possible to have different throttle intervals for different workbook or is it just application wide?

Comment: Afaik, no, it's not. You can only set update time on specific `Workbook`s

Comment: Furthermore, from practical standpoint, it makes no sense to update only a specific `Worksheet` while leaving the others unupdated

Comment: sorry- the use of the word worksheet in the last line was a typo. I meant to say workbook. I only need a different workbooks to pull data at different speeds. I'll edit

Comment: I guess you could change the `RTD.ThrottleInterval` property depending on which workbooks are currently open in the `Application` object, however from practical standpoint, I would say it's better to simply leave the `ThrotteInterval` same for every `Workbook`. Perhaps there is some more elegant solution, but at least I am not aware of one